# TreeView focus/selection and button/mouse area delegate

Tags: delegates, treeview, focus, qml

I have a `TreeView`and I have an image with a `MouseArea` in one of the columns. By clicking on it, the focus (selection, highlighting?) doesn't move to the string because the `MouseArea` is above the `TreeView` (as far as I understand)

Here is the code:

```
  TreeView 
  { 
    clip: true id: mapsTreeView 
    objectName: "mapsTreeView" 
    model: theModel

    TableViewColumn {
        width: 100
        role: "name_role"
        title: "Map"
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        width: 50
        role: "description_role"
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        id: imageColumn
        width: 20
        role: "image_role"
        delegate: Item {
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    mapsTreeView.sigChangeState()
                }
            }
            Image {
                anchors.fill: parent
                width: 5
                source: "icon" + styleData.value + ".png"
            }
        }

        }
        signal sigChangeState()
    }
}
```

The same story applies to the button:

```
TableViewColumn {
            id: imageColumn
            width: 20
            role: "image_role"
            delegate: Button {
                    iconSource: "icon" + styleData.value + ".png"
                    onClicked: mapsTreeView.sigChangeState()
                    }
 }
```

When I click on the button, the focus doesn't moves to the string that contains button.

So the question is, how to make the image/button delegate so that by clicking on it focus will move to the string that contains this object, and some signal is emitted.

In `ListView`, all I had to do was simply the following:

```
onClicked:{
   mapsView.currentIndex=model.index
   mapsState.sigChangeState()
}
```

But `TreeView` doesn't allow one to write `CurrentIndex`